# Component - Subclass event c#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, components, subclass

I have a class what I would like to close into a component. I try to make it work, based on the following code,

The issue is, that the properties are editable and viewable in the property browser & the Test Event is viewable but it cannot be filled form the property browser, just from the code.

How can I solve this anomaly?

```
namespace TestComponents
{
  public partial class Test: Component
  {
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public SubClass SubClass { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      SubClass = new SubClass();
    }
  }

  public delegate void TestEventHandler(Object sender, TestEventArgs e);

  public class TestEventArgs: EventArgs
  {
    public Boolean Test { get; set; }

    public TestEventArgs(Boolean ATest): base()
    {
      Test = ATest;
    }
  }

  [TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(System.ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter))]
  public class SubClass
  {
    public Boolean TestProperty { get; set; }
    public event TestEventHandler TestEvent;

    protected virtual void OnTestEvent(TestEventArgs e)
    {
      if (TestEvent != null)
        TestEvent(this, e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. If the subclass inherited from Component, the Visual Studio can manage "subclass events" well.

Answer (score 0):

Suspect the property editor doesn't know how it should handle input related to the complex TestEventArgs class, so you can't edit in in the Visual Studio property editor.

You could have a look at writing a [Custom UI Type Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx) and then specify the custom editor by using the `EditorAttribute`:

```
[EditorAttribute(typeof(YourCustomEditor),typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
```

Comment: But if I'm declaring event inside the component directly, not in the subclass, then for double click the Visual Studio will create the code for this event automatically, without  declaring any editor attribute...

Comment: I'm confused. According to your code, your event IS inside the subclass? What object is the property grid displaying properties for? Test or Subclass? Screenshot might help here.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean now. I suspect then, it's a limitation of the PropertyGrid to support double-click event add for events exposed using DesignerSerializationVisibility. May work if you create a Custom UI Type Editor for Subclass as I've suggested above rather, than using DesignerSerializationVisibility to force it into the Test Property Grid?